# How to add to each element of an array

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrays

I'm trying to take each element of an array that's generated from a SPLIT function and do some math on them, specifically, I want to add 3 to each element.

1. Cell starts off with this: `1,2,3,4,5`
2. SPLIT function turns this into an array: `1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5`
3. Adding 3 to each elements turns it into this: `4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8`

I've been searching seemingly forever, to no avail. It would be great if there was a simple solution like some kind of increment function that returns another array like this: `INCREMENT(SPLIT(AB37,","),3)`

Have someone done something like this before?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Try `=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(AB37,",")+3)`, if you need further help please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Thank you, you're answer works. On another topic, it feels a little hostile that the moderator in Super User and yourself are linking "How to Ask" and "Help Center" links, inferring that I'm carelessly posting. Stack Exchange has a RIDICULOUS amount of sites, it's difficult for new users to know, for example, that Google Sheets is a "Web Applications" question and not a Super User question that says that I can ask about "Computer Software". And how do I describe my search efforts in a way that's useful? Nobody cares about the hundred Google search terms I used to come up with nothing, right?

Answer (score 1):

@Rubén was quick and correct, his answer works.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(AB37,",")+3)
```